# WCF service reference in .NET Core. Need to specify a Via address

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I'm communicating with a rather old-school WCF/ASMX webservice and I was given this old .net framework/WSE code as an example:

```
var _serviceAddress = "urn:some-urn-removed-here";
var _referralVia = "https://the-actual-webservice-url.com/something.asmx"; // <- This should be the actual URL of the service

Uri uriServiceAddress = new Uri(_serviceAddress);
UriBuilder uribuilderViaRouter = new UriBuilder(_referralVia);
EndpointReference address = new EndpointReference(uriServiceAddress, uribuilderViaRouter.Uri);
```

The problem is that in .NET Core, the EndpointReference constructor only takes one parameter and after some Google-ing (And Chat-GPT-ing) I cannot seem to find a way to do this in .NET Core.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can refer to [the project](https://github.com/CoreWCF/samples/blob/main/Scenarios/Logging-and-Dependency-Injection/LoggingSampleClient/Connected%20Services/ServiceReference1/Reference.cs) to see if it can solve your problem.